# How to make startx use alternate xinitrc?

Tags: xorg, configuration, gui, session

I don't have a desktop manager installed (and I don't want to). After logging in through the terminal I use `startx` to start the GUI. I have entries in `~/.xinitrc` for my GUI sessions. Right now I have xmonad in there, but sometimes I want to run a GNOME session, and sometimes a KDE session. I used to edit `~/.xinitrc` for that purpose, but I think there should be a more elegant way (something like using alternate configurations). However, I can't find anything in `man startx` or `man xinit`.

I plan to have several configuration files (one for each GUI session), and then tell `startx` to load them when I want. How can I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [`xinit` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xinit) that I read, `xinit` (and thereby `startx`) looks in its command line parameters for a client program to run.  If it doesn't find one, it runs `~/.xinitrc` instead.  So you should be able to write

```
startx path/to/my_alternate_xinitrc
```

and it will do what you want.  You will need to provide a path, though, and not just a filename.  In my testing, `startx ./my_xinitrc` worked but `startx my_xinitrc` did not.

Comment: The file name thing is weird, anyway this answer works for me, thanks!

Comment: In my case the path must be absolute. The relative paths not work.